# Normalize(Scale) data before sampling or after sampling in binary classification?

Tags: sampling, sample-size, normalization

I have a binary classification database with imbalance outputs (1 labeled data: 1400 samples, 0 labeled data: 200 samples). I balance data based on a criteria to (200 - 200). Where should I normalize data based on mean and standard deviation (SD)? before sampling (1400-200) or after sampling (200-200)? I have 10 input features to normalize,

Answer (score 0):

The general rule of thumb is to first upsample/downsample your dataset and then perform any kind of scaling.
Please check this post on stackoverflow for more details:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70130741/python-should-data-scaling-be-done-before-sampling-in-machine-learning